# Newly deployed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, experiencing a non-showstopper nuisance error Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL?

Tags: 22.04, qt, plasma-5

I built a new server instance on Kamatera cloud. The release was stripped to the core, yet the install was superbly clean.

1. Installed Firefox

   `$ sudo apt install firefox`
2. Attempted to install NoMachine resulting in a stall and abort; there wasn't a desktop installed.
3. So, I installed No Frills Plasma (minimal install), the latest Wine, and Windows software I need to run under Wine. Ez-Pz and A-OK.
4. Installed NoMachine - no quirks, installed and the system is clean as a whistle.
5. Connected, everything 100% percent, 0-Defects;
6. Then, I found that Kate wasn't installed as part of the minimal Plasma build; no worries; installed Kate, Kompare, and Ksnip; everything works exceedingly well.
7. Then, I launched Kate from a Konsole and got a few errors, one was about a 'missing' (not-installed) word check dictionary (fixed), and the other issue is the main reason for this question:

**Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL**

That said, it's a non-critical 'error' and doesn't seem to impact Kate's operational capabilities, but it is annoying. After looking into some of the potential causes, Ubuntu seemed to be aware of this as early as 2015 - a bug - that was most likely fixed long, long ago. Some speculators attribute the issue to Dolphin which works 100% with zero defects as well.

Anyway the system is behaving, performing better than expected. I just thought I'd share this incident with the community to see if it jogs anyone's memory.

[image: Picture of the "Issue"]

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
```

```
$ wine --version
$ wine-8.0.2
```

Comment: Ubuntu server is command line only. It does not have any GUI. If you want a GUI, install the desktop version.

Comment: Negative, sir. I need (and prefer) GUI servers - the Desktop bloatware in a production environment is avoidable - and - is it really possible to manage wine apps without a GUI? I hadn't considered this as a possibility but, if you are aware of a better solution, do tell.

Comment: You can use the desktop installer and choose to have a minimal install with just Firefox, Text Editor, Nautilus etc. See [this image](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/jammy-wizard-install.jpg). Once you have it installed, you may uninstall whatever you don't need and install what you need.